# How to correctly implement a validated login block in sqlite3 c++ database

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, authentication

I need to implement a login lock in who the user enters data, and they are compared with entries in the database, if both the login and password match, in order to continue the program, if not, send the data entry test again.

#But my problem is that I don't know how to implement such a request#

[enter image description here][1]

```
static int selectData(const char* s, string login, string password)
{
    sqlite3* DB;
    char* messageError;
    
    string sql = "SELECT Login, Password INTO '"+ login +"','"+ password +"' FROM Users WHERE Status = 1";

    int exit = sqlite3_open(s, &DB);
    exit = sqlite3_exec(DB, sql.c_str(), callback, NULL, &messageError);

    if (exit != SQLITE_OK) {
        cerr << "Error in selectData function." << endl;
        sqlite3_free(messageError);
    }
    else
        cout << "Records selected Successfully!" << endl;

    return 0;
}

static int callback(void* NotUsed, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) 
    {
        cout << azColName[i] << ": " << argv[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}

void SignIN(const char* dir)
{
    string login, password;
    cout << "Login: ";
    cin >> login;
    cout << "Password: ";
    cin >> password;

    selectData(dir);
        
        // Other code.......
}
```

```
help me please


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQcul.png
```

Comment: `static int selectData(const char* s, string login, string password)` requires 3 parameters but you called it with 1 `selectData(dir);`

Comment: `selectData()` is probably not a good name for a login / password checking function. Also it probably should return different values if the correct password matched the username in the database versus not matching. That way you can do something different depending on if the login was a success or failure.